# Convert String to callable methods in JAVA

Tags: java, casting

I have a string and a class with a set of functions.

As for example, String is

```
String tr = "ctx.mkLt(ctx.mkIntConst(\"x\"),ctx.mkInt(100))";
```

And the class as `Context ctx = new Context();` with methods as `ctx.mkLt(arg 0, arg 1), ctx.mkIntConst(arg 0, arg 1)` and others.

I am not able to convert the string into callable methods of class *ctx*.

Is there a way to convert the string into the callable method of class as in the above case?

Comment: The reflection api or nashorn... need more context; but if you search with google on either (or both) of those you should find examples.

Comment: This is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to simulate embedding a Java interpreter in your program, which is almost certainly the most complicated way to do whatever you're trying to do. Why do you think you need this functionality?